# Making key value pairs from an HDFS sequence file using Apache Spark

Tags: scala, hdfs, apache-spark

What is the best way to make key value pairs out of a HDFS sequence file?  The reason why I am asking, I have to sort a sequence file.  The sortByKey method is not available unless your RDD is in the form of key value pairs.  I am using Apache Spark 1.0.2 and HDFS 2.5.0 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Spark documentation :

> For SequenceFiles, use SparkContext’s sequenceFile[K, V] method where
>   K and V are the types of key and values in the file. These should be
>   subclasses of Hadoop’s Writable interface, like IntWritable and Text.
>   In addition, Spark allows you to specify native types for a few common
>   Writables; for example, sequenceFile[Int, String] will automatically
>   read IntWritables and Texts.

Key point is that you have to map Hadoop Types to [String, Int, ...] and built your desired (k,v) rdd in order to apply sortByKey method.

```
val file = sc.sequenceFile(input, classOf[Text], classOf[Text])
val map = file.map{case (k,v) => (k.toString(), v.toString())} 
val sortedOutput = map.sortByKey(true)
```

Comment: That is the code that I came up with too.  I am having trouble with it scaling with larger datasets (>= 500GB).  It spills to disk during the shuffle phase and this is where my job dies on larger data sets.  It runs the workers out of physical disk space.  I know that I could move the path where it is writing to a larger drive, but that just seems lame.  For a 32 GB dataset, my job will shuffle 74.5 GB.  This seems odd to me.  Any thoughts?  TIA

Comment: I don't know the reason of that but I've seen that in release 1.1.0 introduces a new shuffle implementation optimized for very large scale shuffles.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2045
http://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-1-0.html

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the signature with native type parameters such that the method only requires the file path. You don't explicitly need to do an extra step to map it into a typed RDD.

```
val file = sc.sequenceFile[Text, Text](file_path)
```

The above statement would load and map data to the Types specified in the Signature. You can then apply sort operation on it.

```
sortedData = file.sortByKey(true)
```

Hope this helps.